# c# datatable Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetDataTable(@"C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Desktop\ACTIVITYEX.log");
        }
        public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string strFileName)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = 
                new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
                    ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " 
                    + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) 
                    + ";Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=TabDelimited\"");
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
            System.Data.DataTable ds = new System.Data.DataTable("CSV File");
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

when THE SAME file is named `.csv` it does not give me an error; however when i rename it to `.log` it says `Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.` on `adapter.Fill`

is this a compiler error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it's a not a compiler error. If anything it's an error from the OleDb Jet engine. I have ran into enough problems with Jet in the past so I usually avoid it. You might save yourself lots of debugging time by using [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

An old post, but I just stepped into that problem.
Please refer to this article : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245407

Long story short : Jet Engine only accepts a few file extension when reading CSV File (Extended properties=TEXT,etc..).

Solutions :

1. rename your file in a temp folder when reading it
2. read it with another mecanism than JET (standard File.io.ReadAllLines)
3. Add the extension in the windows registry as pointed out by antonio Bukala

Answer (score -1):

*.log is disabled extension, AFAIK only way is registry change on machine that will run this code, see MS Knowledge base [article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;304206)

Comment: i renamed it to .log1 still the same msg

Comment: did you add log extension in registry ? I know that it sounds unbeleivable but you have to add it to registry key Disabled extensions because there is one !  in front, and that apparantly means not, if ! is used these are allowed extensions. wierd, here is a detailed explanation: http://access.mvps.org/access/bugs/bugs0046.htm